# Location of the first zero of the zeta function over finite field

Tags: number-theory, zeta-functions

I know that first non-trivial zero of the Riemann zeta function with imaginary part different from zero is 14.13....

Does anybody knows for rational zeta function associated to the function field $K$ of an arbitrary genus over a finite field of constants which is first zero ...?

Comment: Are you looking for an exact formula? An asymptotic formula? A statistical distribution?

Comment: I just need the bound of the first zero...

Comment: [Here is a paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X14002625) that will help you begin a search through the literature.

Comment: I had read this paper, but there is no info about zeta function over finite field.